# Windows 10 USB 3.0 Issue on AMD Ryzen B350 Motherboard

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, graphics-card, motherboard

## The Issue at Hand

The 4 Rear USB 3.0 ports on my motherboard do not work in Windows 10. I have attempted to install the AMD B350 Chipset drivers from both the [AMD website](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset/previous/detail?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064&rev=17.30) and the [Manufacturer site](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350-PC-MATE#down-driver&Win10%2064) but they fail to install and produce a working USB 3.0 driver.

I can detect devices such as a keyboard or usb drive in BIOS and can boot into a Linux Live environment off of the USB 3.0 ports as well as use a keyboard and transfer files between the USB 3.0 ports. They simply do not work in Windows 10. This has been an ongoing problem since I built this computer in July.

## Computer Specifications

- AMD Ryzen r5 1600 Processor
- MSI B350 PC Mate Motherboard
- AMD RX 480 4 GB MSI Gaming X Graphics Card
- Windows 10 Education 1709 (Installed as 1607)
- Various Wired and Wireless Keyboards and USB Drives

## What I have done so far

As noted above I have downloaded the available chipset drivers for my motherboard at both [AMD](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset/previous/detail?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064&rev=17.30) and [MSI](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350-PC-MATE#down-driver&Win10%2064), but they fail to install properly. They overwrite or conflict with my Graphics Driver when I use the installer. When I search through the folder for the specific Windows driver file and attempt to manually install the USB 3.0 controllers, Windows reports that this is an update for Windows 7 and incompatible with this system.

## Possible Solution

According to this [thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/6hm593/ryzen_psa_you_need_to_reinstall_the_amd_chipset/), if you want to install the chipset drivers you must wipe out all of the old AMD drivers using a clean install utility such as DDU or the AMD cleanup tool, then install the chipset drivers first before the graphics driver.

I just want to know if anyone else has had this issue and if the possible solution will work before I move forward.

Comment: USB3.x drivers are already included in Windows 10. Whatever you've been installing 1) it's NOT for Windows 10 and 2) can only make it worse.

Comment: The front panel USB 3.0 ports work, it is only the rear USB 3.0 ports that do not work in Windows 10 to clarify, and is [Microsoft Imagine](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us) not a safe place to get Windows 10?

Comment: @kemotep - You might want to read what Michael said again, the USB 3 drivers you have been installing, are not intended to be installed on Windows 10.  You indicated you attempted to install the chipset drivers, I presume you have verified, they are specifically Windows 10 compatible?

Comment: As I suspected..."Include AMD SMBus Driver、GPU Display Driver、AMD **USB Controller Driver(only WIN7)**."  What you have been downloading isn't intended to even be installed on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound, that is effectively the question I am posing. I apologize if it isn't clear. The drivers from AMD and MSI state that they are for Windows 10 64-bit but the USB drivers inside the directory that you download are labeled as for Windows 7. I am asking if the proposed solution will get my rear USB ports working or not. If MichealBay is correct then my MSI B350 has only 4 out of 8 working USB ports with the drivers provided by Microsoft, MSI and AMD which is why I am here asking if anyone has experience with this.

Comment: "if the proposed solution will get my rear USB ports working or not." - I suspect the solution is only applicable to Windows 7 and below.  Reddit is extremely slow for me today.

Comment: @Ramhound, When I get home I'm still going to test the instructions given in the reddit thread but it seems odd that the new B350 Ryzen chipset does not have drivers for USB 3.0 ports for Windows 10.

Comment: @kemotep - You install the chipset drivers.  USB 3 drivers are built into Windows 10.  Vendor-specific USB 3 drivers have not been required since Windows 8.  *Since you don't specify the error you receive, when you installed the chipset, I can't solve that problem.*  The chipset drivers are required to add the power profile, which allows Windows in general, to use the tuned power profile required to use a Ryzen CPU properly.  *That is really the only reason for the chipset driver.*

Comment: I should add Windows 10 will automatically download both the appropriate chipset driver and display driver automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73599/discussion-between-kemotep-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing I have found the solution thanks to user Ramhound. Windows 10 device manager had to be forced to find USB 3.0 drivers manually using this [method](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028443/windows-update-drivers-in-windows-10) and now all USB ports work. No other steps seem to be needed however I did update to the latest BIOS, chipset, and graphics drivers anyway.